# Finding Symmetry number of a molecule

Tags: molecules, symmetry, isotope

[image: Problem Statement]

An isotopic variant of the molecule SF$_6$ is S$^{19}$F$_4^{18}$F$_2$, with the two $^{18}$F nuclei oriented axially, so that the $^{18}$F-S-$^{18}$F angle is 180°and the four $^{19}$F nuclei form a square in a plane perpendicular to the $^{18}$F-S-$^{18}$F axis. All of the bond lengths are equal.  In the figure, the regions surrounding the $^{18}$F nuclei are shown in blue, and the regions around the $^{19}$F nuclei are shown in green.Two of the moments of inertia of S$^{19}$F$_4^{18}$F$_2$ are identical, and the third is slightly larger: I$_A$= I$_B$ = $2.9942 ×10^{-45}$ kg m$^2$ and I$_C$= $3.0749×10^{-45}$ kg m$^2$. Wikipedia describes SF$_6$ as an “extremely potent greenhouse gas.”

What is the symmetry number of S$^{19}$F$_4^{18}$F$_2$?

I have considered it and think there is one 4-fold axis, and two 2 fold axes, but still unsure if that is right

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange! Please edit your question to show your efforts at solving the problem

Comment: I made one edit, but haven't really been able to get anywhere as I am very confused!

Comment: One way to think about it is: Start from SF$_6$ without any isotope labeling, and see what point group you get. What symmetry operations do you lose when you change the two axial fluorines to $^{18}$F?

Comment: SF6 has three 4-fold axes (counting for 3 each) -> 9, four 3-fold axes (each counting for 2) -> 8, and six 2-fold axes (each counting for 1) -> 6, plus the identity so the symmetry number is 24

Comment: [Not even close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry).

Comment: I am more confused with the addition of the isotope, so is there one 4-fold, two 2-fold, and I'm not sure how the 3-fold would work here..

Comment: See https://www.chemtube3d.com/octahedral-sulfur-hexafluoride-sf6-symmetry/ for exploring the O$_h$ symmetry of the untagged (all $^{19}$F SF$_6$. Which operations do you lose when you do the replacement I mentioned above?

Comment: If you assume that your molecule is of the form $\ce{AB4C2}$ then one form is that shown in your figure and belongs to the  $D_{4h}$ point group, the other has the two blue atoms at 90 deg to one another and belongs to $C_{2v}$